# How can i make an IF statement that only runs if a certain variable id is sent via URL?

Tags: php, ajax, logic

Is it possible to make an IF clause in php that will only trigger if i have encoded a specific variable in the url?

I have a php page which will get and output query results without page refresh. When a user clicks on a specific query result, that value is sent via url to the same page which then reruns this script with that query result as the new search parameter.

Only thing is, first time the page is run i need to find a way to bypass the echo statements and the attempts to $_GET data from the url, because there is none.

so essentially some kind of if clause that could be like

```
IF(url variable value = 'id')
{
$variabledata=$_GET['var1'];
echo $variabledata;
}

ELSE nothing
```

Comment: you should use `==` for comparison, and `=` for assignment. I assume you don't want to assign a variable inside an `if` condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['var1'])) {
   $variabledata=$_GET['var1'];
   echo $variabledata;
}
```

so the content of the `if` block will only be executed if the parameter `var1` was sent.

Answer (score 1):

you can check this when you get the url

```
if (isset($_GET['var1']) &&  $variabledata=$_GET['var1']) {
     echo $variabledata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST` works for `GET` and `POST`

```
if($_REQUEST['url_variable_value'] == 'id'){
    $variabledata=$_GET['var1'];
    echo $variabledata;
} else {
    // nothing
}


// http://example.com/somewhere/?url_variable_value=id&var1=the_data
// output: "the_data"
```